# Recently viewed products on show in sub-categories

Tags: product

I have the problem that the recently viewed products block only appear when I'm in one of my sub-categories and not in my parent category.
I haven't worked with Magento before, so I don't know where to look.
I did however find product_viewed.phtml, but it doesn't look like there is anything in the file, that defines that it should only be showed in sub-categories. Where else should i look?
Below is my product_viewed.phtml file.

```
<?php if ($_products = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts()): ?>
<div class="block block-list block-viewed">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Recently Viewed Products') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <ol id="recently-viewed-items">
        <?php foreach ($_products as $_item): ?>
            <li class="item">
                <p class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_item) ?>"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_item, $_item->getName() , 'name') ?></a></p>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('recently-viewed-items');</script>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: normally recently viewed products are showing in root category. this is a fresh installation ?

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364493/magento-last-viewed-products-only-shown-parent-categories